# Why is this Json parse error not being caught in typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm new to typescript and javascript and I'm not sure why this is happening. I have some typescript that tries to parse some json. Sometimes the json can't be parsed and results in a syntax error. I'm trying to catch this error and display a message (simplified in the example), but it looks like it's not working.

```
  try {
        let item: SomeItem = JSON.parse(data.someItem)
        return (
            <div>
                ... // a bunch of stuff using the item
            </div>
        )
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log("Debug - exception caught?")
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Error retrieving the some item info</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

When I run this and the JSON can't be parsed, the error doesn't seem to be getting caught. Any thoughts?

Edit:

Q: What does the compiled JavaScript look like?

```
"use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  require("../css/table.css");
  require("../../../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css");
  var React = require("react");
  exports.ItemDetailPage = function (info) {
      var data = info.data;
      try {
          let item: SomeItem = JSON.parse(data.someItem);
          return (
              <div>
                 ... // a bunch of stuff using the item
              </div>
          );
      }
      catch (err) {
          console.log("Debug - exception caught?")
          return (
              <div>
                  <p>Error retrieving the some item info</p>
              </div>
          );
      }
  };
```

Q2: Also, how do you know that the JSON can't be parsed? What do you get from item?
When the value can be parsed, I can get any attribute from SomeItem, which is just a few strings and numbers. 
This is what shows up in the console output:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]
```

Comment: What's the compiled javascript look like?

Comment: Also, how do you know that the JSON can't be parsed? What do you get from item?

Comment: @CodyG. - Added details to answer your question at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting your JSON.parse in its own try/catch without the class (just use any) and see what happens? I don't really see why it wouldn't be caught D:

Comment: @CodyG: Yes, it's strange. I tried that as well and still get the same error.

Comment: I wrote a basic example without your return ( <html> ) (and instead a return obj; ) and it worked fine, so maybe it is something not being caught in the parsing of that?